# Get certificate details from java key store

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, sim-card

Friends,

**Problem Statement:**
An external entity sends the **serial number** of a certificate to my system. And  using that serial number my system has to find out or fetch certificate details (Ex: by online downloading or by pre-load using Java Key Store) and use it for signature verification.

I could not find how to download certificate from online using serial number. But, I wouldn't ouch for even though it was, since you know why.

Instead, i would like to go with Java Key Store (JKS) and fetch certification details. But JKS expects alias name and password.

So, now do you suggest me to go to that external entity guy and ask him to send the certification details instead of serial number? if so is that security compliance? since we are working on Telecom domain using Remote Provisioning Architecture for Embedded UICC Technical Specification Versio 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAs only publish their root and intermediate certificates. The serial number is not usually used to download them, but a URL is included in the final issued certificates.

Summarizing: you can't find a certificate by serial number except if your CA has a specific service to download it, or you have a pre-provisioned list of the CA certificates, for example in a keystore.

Assuming you have a keystore with possible certificates, you can list all available aliases, load the certificate and check if serial number match the provided one. You do not need any password at all.

```
 Enumeration enumeration = keystore.aliases();
 while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        String alias = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(alias);
        BigInteger serialNumber = certificate.getSerialNumber()

    }
```

Note that the serial number is not unique between different CAs

Comment: Thanks a lot friend.. your pointers are now my starting point. I tried to investigate after your reply, but for my problem, say i have different MNO (Mobile N/w Operators) sending me the certificate serial number and i have to authorize their signature.. with your above explanation, it is clear that pre-provisioning is the best alternative, (as thr is no facility to download online using serial number), but are their any way to get the certificate details from keystore without serial number?

Comment: You can get all available certificates with `keystore.aliases()`, then load the `X509Certificate` using the alias. See javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html You have there all the certificate data

Comment: Thanks again!!! this discussion fullfills all my requirement.. Cheers to  pedrofb